# Least CPU intensive way to Frequently & Repeately Draw Many Views

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, ipad, quartz-graphics

This Is a problem that I've been leaving and coming back to for a while now. I've never really nailed the problem.

What I've been trying to do use CADisplayLink to dynamically draw pie chart style progress. My code works fine when I have 1 - 4 uiviews updating simultaneously. When I add any more than that the drawing of the pies becomes very jerky.

I want to explain what I have been trying in the hope that somebody could point out the inefficiencies and suggest a better drawing method.

I create 16 uiviews and add a CAShapeLayer subview to each one. This is where I want to draw my pie slices.

I precalcuate 360 CGPaths representing 0 to 360 degrees of a circle  and store them in an array to try and improve performance.

In a master View  I start a displaylink,loop through all my other views, calculate how much of a full pie it should show, then find the right path and assign it to my shapelayer.

```
-(void)makepieslices
{
    pies=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:360];
    float progress=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=360;i++)

    {
        progress= (i* M_PI)/180;
        CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath, NULL, 0.f, 0.f);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(thePath, NULL, 28, 0.f);
        CGPathAddArc(thePath, NULL, 0.f,0.f, 28, 0.f, progress, NO);
        CGPathCloseSubpath(thePath);
        _pies[i]=thePath;


    }



}

- (void)updatePath:(CADisplayLink *)dLink {

    for (int idx=0; idx<[spinnydelegates count]; idx++) {

        id<SyncSpinUpdateDelegate> delegate = [spinnydelegates objectAtIndex:idx];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        [delegate updatePath:dLink];
        });

    }






}

- (void)updatePath:(CADisplayLink *)dLink {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

        currentarc=[engineref getsyncpercentForPad:cid pad:pid];

        int progress;

        progress = roundf(currentarc*360);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            shapeLayer_.path = _pies[progress];

        });



    });


}
```

This technique just straight out isnt working for me when trying to simultaneously update more than 4 or 5 pies at the same time. 16 screen updates at the same time sounds like it should really not be that big of a deal for the ipad to me. So this leads me to think I doing something very very fundamentally  wrong.

I'd really appreciate if somebody could tell me why this technique results in jittery screen updates and also if they could suggest a different technique that I could go an investigate that will allow me to perform 16 simultaneous shapelayer updates smoothly.

**EDIT** Just to give you an idea of how bad performance is, when I have all 16 pies drawing the cpu goes up to 20%

**EDIT **

This is based on studevs advice but I don't see anything been drawn. segmentLayer is a CGLayerRef as a property of my pieview.

```
-(void)makepies
{

    self.layerobjects=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:360];

    CGFloat progress=0;

    CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    for(int i =0;i<360;i++)
    {
        progress= (i*M_PI)/180.0f;

        CGLayerRef segmentlayer=CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, CGSizeMake(30, 30), NULL);
        CGContextRef layerContext=CGLayerGetContext(segmentlayer);
        CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath, NULL, 0.f, 0.f);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(thePath, NULL, 28, 0.f);
        CGPathAddArc(thePath, NULL, 0.f,0.f, 28, 0.f, progress, NO);
        CGPathCloseSubpath(thePath);

        [layerobjects addObject:(id)segmentlayer];
        CGLayerRelease(segmentlayer);
    }

}



-(void)updatePath
{
    int progress;

    currentarc=[engineref getsyncpercent];
    progress = roundf(currentarc*360);


    //shapeLayer_.path = _pies[progress];

    self.pieView.segmentLayer=(CGLayerRef)[layerobjects objectAtIndex:progress];

    [self.pieView setNeedsDisplay];


}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextDrawLayerInRect(context, self.bounds, segmentLayer);

}
```

Comment: Do you stroke or fill the paths? If you are filling them, does closing the cached paths improve performance? Probably not the main culprit, but still...

Comment: closing the cached paths didnt improve the situation. I dont stroke the paths, I fill them.

Comment: If you're using CADisplayLink make sure you are only updating the views when something has actually changed, otherwise you're just redrawing everything 60 times per second for no reason.

Comment: do you need to draw at the display's refresh rate?

Comment: @Justin. The progress of the pie drawing is supposed to represent the progress of an mp3s playback progress so I guess at the displays refresh rate at a minimum

Comment: @dubbeat the draw frequency may be reduced - I've added an answer with details.

Comment: I'm guessing that, because you don't have a separate opaque background behind each chart, every time one chart is redrawn the whole screen is redrawn.

Comment: "Would welcome ideas of other approaches to try."  This won't answer your question, but a possible alternative is the Moriarty Pie Chart http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=104 and the git link https://github.com/tylerneylon/moriarty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think one of the first things you should look to do is buffer your segments (currently represented by `CGPath` objects) offscreen using `CGLayer` objects. From the docs:

> Layers are suited for the following:
>
> - High-quality offscreen rendering of drawing that you plan to reuse.
>     For example, you might be building a scene and plan to reuse the same
>     background. Draw the background scene to a layer and then draw the
>     layer whenever you need it. One added benefit is that you don’t need
>     to know color space or device-dependent information to draw to a
>     layer.
> - Repeated drawing. For example, you might want to create a
>     pattern that consists of the same item drawn over and over. Draw the
>     item to a layer and then repeatedly draw the layer, as shown in Figure
>     12-1. Any Quartz object that you draw repeatedly—including CGPath,
>     CGShading, and CGPDFPage objects—benefits from improved performance if
>     you draw it to a CGLayer. Note that a layer is not just for onscreen
>     drawing; you can use it for graphics contexts that aren’t
>     screen-oriented, such as a PDF graphics context.

Create a `UIView` subclass that draws the pie. Give it an instance variable for that pie's current progress, and override `drawRect:` to draw the layer representing that progress. The view needs to first get a reference the required `CGLayer` object, so implement a delegate with the method:

```
- (CGLayerRef)pieView:(PieView *)pieView segmentLayerForProgress:(NSInteger)progress context:(CGContextRef)context;
```

It will then become the delegate's job to return an existing `CGLayerRef`, or if it doesn't exist yet, create it. Since the `CGLayer` can only be created from within `drawRect:`, this delegate method should be called from `PieView`'s `drawRect:` method. `PieView` should look something like this:

`PieView.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@class PieView;

@protocol PieViewDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (CGLayerRef)pieView:(PieView *)pieView segmentLayerForProgress:(NSInteger)progress context:(CGContextRef)context;

@end


@interface PieView : UIView

@property(nonatomic, weak) id <PieViewDelegate> delegate;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger progress;

@end
```

`PieView.m`

```
#import "PieView.h"


@implementation PieView

@synthesize delegate, progress;

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGLayerRef segmentLayer = [delegate pieView:self segmentLayerForProgress:self.progress context:context];
    CGContextDrawLayerInRect(context, self.bounds, segmentLayer);
}

@end
```

Your `PieView`'s delegate (most likely your view controller) then implements:

```
NSString *const SegmentCacheKey = @"SegmentForProgress:";

- (CGLayerRef)pieView:(PieView *)pieView segmentLayerForProgress:(NSInteger)progress context:(CGContextRef)context
{
    // First, try to retrieve the layer from the cache
    NSString *cacheKey = [SegmentCacheKey stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", progress];
    CGLayerRef segmentLayer = (__bridge_retained CGLayerRef)[segmentsCache objectForKey:cacheKey];

    if (!segmentLayer) {    // If the layer hasn't been created yet
        CGFloat progressAngle = (progress * M_PI) / 180.0f;

        // Create the layer
        segmentLayer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, layerSize, NULL);
        CGContextRef layerContext = CGLayerGetContext(segmentLayer);

        // Draw the segment
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(layerContext, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(layerContext, layerSize.width / 2.0f, layerSize.height / 2.0f);
        CGContextAddArc(layerContext, layerSize.width / 2.0f, layerSize.height / 2.0f, layerSize.width / 2.0f, 0.0f, progressAngle, NO);
        CGContextClosePath(layerContext);
        CGContextFillPath(layerContext);

        // Cache the layer
        [segmentsCache setObject:(__bridge_transfer id)segmentLayer forKey:cacheKey];
    }

    return segmentLayer;
}
```

So for each pie, create a new `PieView` and set it's delegate. When you need to update a pie, update the `PieView`'s `progress` property and call `setNeedsDisplay`.

I'm using an `NSCache` here since there are a lot of graphics being stored, and it could take up a lot of memory. You could also limit the number of segments being drawn - 100 is probably plenty. Also, I agree with other comments/answers that you might try updating the views less often, as this will consume less CPU and battery power (60fps is probably not necessary).

---

I did some crude testing of this method on an iPad (1st gen) and managed to get well over 50 pies updating at 30fps.

Comment: I've tried implementing your suggestion. I however don't see anything getting drawn. Could it be because my makePies function is in the view controller and not in the view?

Comment: It shouldn't matter where your makePies function is, so long as `PieView` is properly passed the reference to the `CGLayerRef`. How are you drawing into the layer? Make sure you draw directly using core graphics drawing calls, rather than using a `CGPath`. Also make sure these drawing calls use `layerContext`, rather than `context`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your edit. Yes, the reason you're not seeing anything being drawn is because you aren't actually drawing anything into the context, you are just constructing a path. The layer will store the drawing as a bitmap, so you need to use calls like `CGContextAddLineToPoint` to construct the path directly on the context and then use `CGContextFillPath` to draw it to the layer.

Comment: does it matter that CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); has a memory address of 0x0 ?

Comment: My original answer was a bit hasty - I have changed it now and it should work fine. The problem you are seeing is indeed that you can't create your makePies function in your view controller (at least, not outside of a `drawRect:` call).

Comment: I implemented your solution minus the __bridge_retain stuff. My compiler doesnt know what it is so maybe I need to update my sdk. Other than that this I the solution that worked for me. I still have very high cpu usage (50%) but the animations are reliably smooth and the UI is responsive. I've learned a lot & am very grateful. Bounty well earned.

Comment: Thanks, and I'm glad it was helpful. The `__bridge_retain` & `__bridge_transfer` & `weak` keywords are features of Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), which is new as of iOS 5. They are just to do with managing ownership of objects. It's not required to make use of ARC even in iOS 5, as you can opt to stick with manual memory management, however I like it because it saves writing a lot of boring retain/release code.

Answer (score 3):

> dubbeat: ...CADisplayLink...
>
> > Justin: do you need to draw at the display's refresh rate?
> >
> > > dubbeat: The progress of the pie drawing is supposed to represent the progress of an mp3s playback progress so I guess at the displays refresh rate at a minimum.

That's much faster than is necessary, unless you're trying to display some really, really, really exotic visualizer, which is very unlikely if your spinner's radius is 28pt. Also, there's no reason to draw faster than the display's frequency.

One side effect is that your spinner's superviews may also updating at this high frequency. If you can make the spinner view opaque, then you can reduce overdrawing of superviews (and subviews if you have them).

60fps is a good number for a really fast desktop game. For an ornament/progress bar, it's far more than necessary.

Try this:

- not using `CADisplayLink`, but the standard view system
- use an `NSTimer` on the main run loop, begin with a frequency of 8 Hz*
- adjust timer to taste

then let us know if that is adequately fast.

*the timer callback calls `[spinner setNeedsDisplay]`

Comment: I tried out using just a timer. I agree that the update doesnt need to happen at the refresh rate and I am now implementing a single timer with time interval of .6 to draw. The performance is still unacceptably poor. Based on StuDevs testing I'm going to now focus my efforts on his suggested method.

Comment: +1 This is a good point and will help CPU performance and improve UI responsiveness.

Comment: @dubbeat Great - if it looks acceptable at that frequency, that would likely have been a huge improvement (neighboring views may force you to draw more frequently than that). Good luck on StuDev's layers approach (which is also the answer I'd have accepted +1).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could achieve some performance improvement by pre-assembling the background view, capturing the image of it, and then just using the image in an image view for the background.  You could go further by capturing a view of the "relatively static" parts of your chart, updating that static view only when necessary.

Comment: Im not sure I fully understand. Currently My background view is just a UIIview containging a png. Is that what you mean? Would 360 individual pie slices saved as images achieve what you mean by "relatively static" ?

Comment: Well, it's hard to say without seeing your app in operation.  Are there portions of the display that change less rapidly than others?

Comment: Not really. Each pie animation represents the playback progress of an mp3 so each pies percent changes very quickly. These pies are pretty much the only thing in my app that moves

Comment: And keep in mind that even when you don't update a portion of the display it may need to be redrawn if the system can't figure out that it won't change.  One biggie is where you have a partial background that you paint over, with a larger background behind that.  Unless the system knows that the partial background is opaque it will want to redraw the larger background every time something in the foreground changes.  So in particular you want to make the backgrounds of your individual charts as separate opaque views.

Answer (score 0):

Store your 360 circle segments as textures and use OpenGL to animate the sequences.

Comment: could you provide a link to an example?